# EclipseLink select collections

Tags: java, jpa, many-to-many, eclipselink, jpql

i have an entity Recette which have a collection of an other entity Tags

```
public class Recette
private List<TagRecette> listeTag;
...

@ManyToMany
public List<TagRecette> getListeTag() {
    if (listeTag !=null) Collections.sort(listeTag);
    return listeTag;
}

@Entity
public class TagRecette
...
private List<Recette> listeRecettes;
...
@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "listeTag", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
public List<Recette> getListeRecettes() {
    return listeRecettes;
}
```

in my DAO i want to select a list of "recettes" with a list of tags which contains one or many tags given in parameters

```
SELECT r FROM Recette r inner join r.listeMembres proprietaire where proprietaire =:membre and r.categorie IN :listeCateg and r.listeTag  in :listeTag
```

it doesn't work and i have an error :

```
java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Erreur de syntaxe : Encountered "NULL" at line 1, column 451
```

is my request malformed?

Comment: You cannot use r.listeTag  in :listeTag as you are asking if a collection is IN the parameter.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: You might try "select distinct r FROM Recette r join r.listeTag tag inner join r.listeMembres proprietaire where proprietaire =:membre and r.categorie IN :listeCateg and tag in :listeTag"

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i want to get a list of recipes which have one or many tags given in parameters. I tried your solution but i have the same error : "java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: Erreur de syntaxe : Encountered "NULL" at ..."

Comment: i found the solution : my entity "Tags" had two primary key and obviously it was a problem. i put juste one and it works